# How to implement mouseover event in Javascript inside of Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, mouseover

I'm writing load tests in `Jmeter` with WebDriver Sampler plugin.
I have a problem with mouseover function. I have tried a lot of solutions/fixes which I found on stackoverflow and similar sites but none works.
I think that importing jquery library to the script could solve my issue, or creating javascript mouseover event.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

var logowanieMenu = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('ctl00_MainMenun0'))

logowanieMenu.mouseover()

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

java.lang.Thread.sleep(800)
```

or

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

var logowanieMenu = $('#ctl00_MainMenun0')

logowanieMenu.mouseover()

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

java.lang.Thread.sleep(800)
```

I've also tried combinations of `logowanieMenu.hover()` and `logowanieMenu.focus()`

I want to accomplish an event that will "hover mouse" over an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `mouseover` function defined in the [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) class, my expectation is that your test is failing on the line where you call it.

I believe you need to use [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class in general and [moveToElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) function in particular, something like:

```
var actions = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(WDS.browser)
actions.moveToElement(logowanieMenu).perform()
```

Example code for demo purposes:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter.apache.org/')
var overview = WDS.browser.findElementByLinkText('Overview')
var actions = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(WDS.browser)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
actions.moveToElement(overview).perform()
java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
var license = WDS.browser.findElementByLinkText('License')
actions.moveToElement(license).perform()
java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

if you run it you will see that first `Overview` link becomes dark and after one second it turns back to red and `License` link becomes dark.

[image]

Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/) to learn more about WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks.

Comment: This is really helpfull and exactly what i was looking for, Thank you very much!